# Design by Contract for Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, design-by-contract

Last year I took a class about the Design By Contract methodology. We programmed in C# with the Contract API that Mircosoft Research created, and generated unit tests with PEX. This year, I am programming iphone apps in xcode. I am wondering if there exists a library that allows me to use Design By Contract, and a tool to generate unit tests simular to PEX that works for Objective-C. I really miss being able to formulate invariants, post - and preconditions.

Do you have any practical experience with the Design by Contract in Objective-C? Any advice you would like to share?

Answer (score 2):

No experience, no advice and I this question was probably marked down because it is so general and doesn't ask a specific software question.

On the other hand .. the magic of google provides gems like [A few Macros for Designing by Contract in Objective-C](http://www.roard.com/contracts/)

Comment: For me question is specific. Response is not.